# App crash when show/hide button

Tags: ios, crash, uigesturerecognizer, show-hide

i implemented a basic type of image gallery (very similar to the Photos app on iPhone) and I have a button that what does is go back when pressed. Well, It works but only in few cases. The image gallery is basically a UIPageControl that has a layer of UIScrollView and on the top the UIImageView. It can pass between pages (so, between images). But the button is only displayed and accessible on the first page. I use a gesture (in this case a tap) to display the button. This button only works well if I don't move out of the 1st page, If I go to the 2nd page and then back to the first, when I tap the screen to display the button the app crashes, It's a little bit complicated explain that. Here's the code I use to display the button:

```
//.h

@interface ImatgesNouViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> {
UIScrollView *bgScorllView;        
UIView *bgView;                           
UIImageView *picImageView;      
UIScrollView *picScrollView;   
UIImageView *preImageView;   
UIImageView *nextImageView;
}

//.m
-(void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didTap:)];
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[tapGesture setDelegate:self];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
}
```

and then load different things for the Image Gallery.

```
-(void) didTap:(id) sender{


if (boto.hidden == YES){

    [picImageView addSubview:boto];



    boto.hidden = NO;
    NSLog(@"apareix");
} else {

    [picImageView addSubview:boto];


    boto.hidden = YES;
    NSLog(@"desapareix");
}

}
```

**I updated the code into the void action, and now I have more details of the problem. With the old code, the button was only displayed on the first page of the image gallery. Now it can be displayed on every page of the image gallery. Now I know when crashes: If I tap the screen to show the button and tap again to hide it, it works as many times as I want. But, if after doing that I want to go to other page, then it crashes. I hope that with this information the problem would be resolved sooner.**

crash log: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '(null)'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x19b6012 0x1448e7e 0x19b5e78 0xedef35 0xff93a2 0x3d5c4f 0x3e7748 0x3e7c9d 0x3ee5ec 0x3f20e7 0x65a89a 0x6599db 0x65b11f 0x65dd6d 0x65dcec 0x655a68 0x3c2fc2 0x3c34a3 0x3a13aa 0x392cf8 0x1800df9 0x1800ad0 0x192bbf5 0x192b962 0x195cbb6 0x195bf44 0x195be1b 0x17ff7e3 0x17ff668 0x39065c 0x1ee8c 0x2395 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)

(sorry for posting the crash log so late)

I don't know whats exactly happening and the reason of this crash. Could be that the gesture recognize for swiping between the images causes this crash (combined with the gesture of one tap). Thanks for the help in advanced!

Comment: We need at least a crash log and some _relevant_ information. No one cares about `NSLogs` or what "(des)apareix" means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. After thinking a little bit, I saw that I have several objects on the top before the button. So, I have to bring the button on the top, but it's easier to do by adding a subview to the view (as the other objects). With this, the button stays at the top always but then, with the tap gesture and the void command, I change its hidden from Yes to NO. Here's the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];    
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didTap:)];
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[tapGesture setDelegate:self];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
[self.view addSubview:boto];
[boto setHidden:YES];     }

-(void) didTap:(id) sender
{
if (boto.hidden == YES){
          [self.view addSubview:boto];
    boto.hidden = NO;
    NSLog(@"apareix");

} else {
    [boto removeFromSuperview];
    boto.hidden = YES;
    NSLog(@"desapareix");
    [self.view addSubview:boto];
}
}
```

Thanks to every one ho helped me, with the help of all yours I'm able to get working that apparently simple thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

Change
action:@selector(didTap)
to
action:@selector(didTap:)

and

Change
-(void) didTap{
to
-(void) didTap: (id)sender{

Comment: @interface ... <...UIGestureRecognizerDelegate...>
Before "[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];",
add "[tapGesture setDelegate:self];".

Comment: @selector(didTap) -> @selector(didTap:)

Comment: If so,,, that's another problem, i think.
You must remove code from didTap except NSLog. And check what's happen. Good luck!

Comment: Ok thanks. If I remove all the code except the NSLog and the boto.hidden = YES/NO, it doesn't work but I know from the nslog that the code works well. I'll see what's the problem now. Thanks again for the help!